# Use package on GitHub as dependency without having Git installed

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, package.json

I have a main package and in its `package.json` there are dependencies to packages on GitHub:

```
"dependencies": {
    "private-package": "user/private-package"
},
```

This all runs fine on my local machine, it downloads and installs the packages.

However this needs to be installed on a hosted container for which I do **not have any rights**. It requires a tarball of the main package and will install all dependencies. This however fails with the following log;

```
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
```

I am not sure on how I can tackle this, there are a couple of routes that I could think of;

1. Package all dependencies locally in the tarball
2. Somehow install Git on the remote container (can I do this using `package.json`?)
3. Some different structure of the Git package that does not require
   Git to install dependencies

Number 1 is the original problem I started with, which caused me to take the GitHub approach (I used local packages before which I cannot seem to make part of the tarball, no matter what).

Is there any way to depend on a GitHub repository so that it can be installed without using Git?

Comment: Specifically, what does "a hosted container" mean? Is there any documentation around its requirements for a tarball and how it handles dependencies? It seems strange that a system offering to install your dependencies for you would not include Git in 2019.

Comment: Chris, I don't know any specifics about the container itself, except that it requires a tarball from npm pack and it executes the command npm install --production. The combination of the install and the lack of git makes it difficult to have local packages

Comment: Can you ask the container provider about this? The lack of `git` sounds like an oversight to me.

Comment: I did today and it is on the planning. Timelines however... :)

Comment: Does the private package have a release or tag? And when you say private, does that mean it requires authentication to access?

Comment: Hey Chris, yes they are managed by me and have release labels and need authentication access. Added an answer on how I did it now (not the greatest route, but might help someone). If you know another way to get git packages without actually having git installed let me know

Comment: Does `"private-package": "https://github.com/<user>/<project>/archive/<tag>.tar.gz"` work?

Comment: Hey Chris, I tested this and although it does download a tarball, using it as a dependency throws a 404 when doing npm install. Could it be that the npm tarball package has a different setup?

Comment: Hey Chris, I finally got it running, used the tarball setup, with a slightly different url (although functionality wise that did not matter);
https://<git-token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/username/reponame/tarball/1.0.0

Can you add your suggestion as an answer, then I can mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! I've added an answer that's slightly different from what you said worked for you. Feel free to add comments or suggest an edit if you think your changes will improve the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to [provide a URL to a source tarball](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#urls-as-dependencies) that will be downloaded and used without requiring Git, e.g something like:

```
"private-package": "https://github.com/<user>/<project>/archive/<tag>.tar.gz"
```

You may also have to deal with GitHub authentication. Instead of using your regular username and password it's probably a good idea to create [an access token](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) that has very restricted access, only giving it what it needs to do its job. This will be required if you use two-factor authentication.

Once you have this token you should be able to add it to the URL, e.g. something like

```
"private-package": "https://<user>:<token>@github.com/<user>/<project>/archive/<tag>.tar.gz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using Chris's solution I had added my local packages to a seperate folder in the package called repo and referenced them in the package.json as;

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-local-package": "file:./repo/my-local-package"
}
```

This can still be a solution if you're packages are not on Git, or the remote server has no internet connection.